# use same elements in v-if and v-else

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating a login/register page with Vue ,
and I have a tab for login and a tab for register .

this is my Template Code :

```
 <transition v-bind:name="TabEffect">
          <div key="1" class="login" v-if="LoginTab">
            <div>
              <label class="inputText" for="email">Email Address</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Test@TestMail.com"/>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label class="inputText" for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Your Password"/>
            </div>
            <button>
              {{ LoginTab ? 'Login' : 'Register' }}
            </button>
            <span class="or">or</span>
            <a href="#!" class="steamLogin">
              <i class="fab fa-steam"></i>
              <span>Login with Steam</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- Register -->
          <div key="2" v-else class="register">
            <div>
              <label class="inputText" for="email">Email Address</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Test@TestMail.com" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label class="inputText" for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Your Password"/>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label class="inputText" for="Cpassword">Repeat Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="Cpassword" id="Cpassword" placeholder="Repeat Password"/>
            </div>
            <button>{{ LoginTab ? 'Login' : 'Register' }}</button>
            <span class="or">or</span>
            <a href="#!" class="steamLogin">
              <i class="fab fa-steam"></i>
              <span>Login with Steam</span>
            </a>
            <!-- End of Register -->
          </div>
        </transition>
```

code works fine but my problem is code repeating , as you see we have this part of code in both `v-if` and `v-else` :

```
<button>{{ LoginTab ? 'Login' : 'Register' }}</button>
<span class="or">or</span>
<a href="#!" class="steamLogin">
  <i class="fab fa-steam"></i>
  <span>Login with Steam</span>
</a>
```

I want this code to be on the transition , but I don't want to repeat a code twice , I tried to use the code outside of both `v-if` and `v-else` , but elements dosen't show at all .

I'm using vue 2.6.11

**Update**

Transition names are `slideLeft` and `slideRight`

SASS Transition Code :

```
.slideLeft-enter-active,.slideRight-enter-active
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out

.slideLeft-leave-active,.slideRight-leave-active
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out

.slideLeft-enter,.slideRight-leave-to
  transform: translateX(-100px)
  position: relative
  opacity: 0

.slideLeft-enter-to,.slideRight-enter-to,.slideLeft-leave ,.slideRight-leave
  transform: translateX(0)
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  width: 100%

.slideLeft-leave-to,.slideRight-enter
  transform: translateX(100px)
  position: relative
  opacity: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the `v-if` in a `<template>` to handle the conditional part, leaving the common part out:

```
<transition v-bind:name="TabEffect">
    <div v-for="(logTab, i) of [true, false]" v-if="logTab" :key="i+1" :class="LoginTab ? 'login' : 'register'">
        <template v-if="LoginTab">
            <div>
                <label class="inputText" for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Test@TestMail.com"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="inputText" for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Your Password"/>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template v-else>
            <div>
                <label class="inputText" for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Test@TestMail.com"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="inputText" for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Your Password"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="inputText" for="Cpassword">Repeat Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="Cpassword" id="Cpassword" placeholder="Repeat Password"/>
            </div>
        </template>

        <button>{{ LoginTab ? 'Login' : 'Register' }}</button>
        <span class="or">or</span>
        <a href="#!" class="steamLogin">
            <i class="fab fa-steam"></i>
            <span>Login with Steam</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</transition>
```

Lastly, as the main `div`'s class also depends on the `LoginTab` variable, we have to put a `:class` to handle it.

On a side note, only the `Repeat password` of your code seems to be the varying part. Still, I left the `email`/`password` in the conditional to be more faithful to your original question. (And because to change this would be very easy.)

Comment: code works well , but now effects in transitions dosen't work

Comment: @AbolfazlGhaemi try the updated code, please. I may have typo'ed somewhere, though;

Comment: Won't the `v-for` create two divs and duplicate the bottom section? I think that should be removed. To get the transition working I think you just need to bring back the `key` that was in the question, making its value conditional on `LoginTab`.

Comment: I have updated the code. The outer `v-if` should take care of the duplication of the bottom section.

Comment: not i get this error : `The 'undefined' variable inside 'v-for' directive should be replaced with a computed property that returns filtered array instead. You should not mix 'v-for' with 'v-if'`

Comment: What is the name of the transition (and custom CSS, if exists) you are using? So I can reproduce it locally here